# Free first part of dynamic memory in C

Tags: c, embedded, esp8266

I'm programming an esp8266 to post data to server. Part of the program buffers the data in case of WiFi absence. However that buffer may become quite large and I need a way to process it in parts when the connection is restored.

```
char* buff = "\0";
\\ I know that realloc() may return NULL and I will fix it later
buff = realloc(buff, strlen(buff)+strlen(data)+1);
strcat(buff, data);
```

When I start processing the buffer I need to do it arbitrary amount of bytes at a time. When I'm done I need to free them only. something like:

```
buff = realloc(buff, strlen(buff)-x);
```

The problem is that I need to free buff[0] to buff[x-1] not buff[x] to buff[strlen(buff)]

Any suggestions of how I do that cleanly without strdup() or other complications?

Also I don't want to store the address of the buffer and free it after the processing is done

Edit: char* buff = calloc(2, 1); indeed but that's not correlated to the main question (which remains unsolved) in any way.

Comment: You can only call `realloc` with a pointer that has been obtained by `malloc`, `calloc` or another `realloc`. Calling `realloc` with any other pointer is UB.

Comment: More to the point, you call `realloc()` on something you couldn't legally `free()` either, you die. Or, your program dies. **If** you're lucky. ;-)

Comment: The way you described it, you want to `memmove()` the contents of `buff[x]..buff[strlen(buff)` down to `buff[0]` before downsizing `buff`. But... would that really be an improvement over just keeping `buff` until you're done?

Comment: divide up the buffer into smaller logical pieces, handle (and free) one piece at a time. It's rarely a good idea to work with massive buffers.

Comment: By starting with `char* buff = "\0";` you are trying to reallocate the address of a string literal. I suggest `char *buff = calloc(2,1);` (2 because your string contains 2 zeros).

Comment: You are essentially asking how to use the realloc function. How about studying what this function does before using it? [RTFM here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc).

Comment: @MichaelWalz One exception: You can call `realloc` with a pointer of NULL in most implementations, and it will behave like `malloc`

Comment: @tofro correct, but it's not on "most implementations" but on "standard conformant implementations".

Comment: Yes indeed I made a mistake in the example code, but that's not the case(in my real programme buff=NULL and in the initialization I use if/else and malloc/realloc, that shouldn't matter though)

Also I know how to use realloc and no one got the point that I need realloc alternative, not qualification of my programming skills(which are quite bad, but OK for 1st year in college)...

Also I didn't consider memmove which will surely work but is quite the waste of CPU resources.

Comment: @HristoMitrev if `memmove` is not an option maybe just leave the buffer grow as suggested in an earlier comment or find another more complex implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just doing:

```
buff = realloc(buff, strlen(buff)-x);
```

which basically just truncates the buffer, you need to move the bytes you want to keep at the beginning of the `buff` pointer and then call `realloc`:

```
int newlength = strlen(buff + x) + 1; // + 1 for the NUL terminator
memmove(buff, buff+x, newlength);  
buff = realloc(buff, newlength);
```

If the buffer is long this may be inefficient. If performance is an issue here, things are getting a bit more complicated.

Comment: Much better +1.  Minor idea: I tend to prefer "length" to refer to the string _length_ and not _size_ and would code `size_t new_size = strlen(buff + x) + 1;`